# Mysql Query with Subquery with group_concat and in dosen't work

Tags: mysql, group-concat

i have some problems with a Query seem IN dosen't work with Group_concat, that is what i wrote

```
SELECT category, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `short` SEPARATOR ', ' )
    FROM `ods_category` 
    WHERE cid IN (n.category) 
    ORDER BY cid
) AS catstring
FROM ods_news AS n
```

the problem is just the column "catstring" containe only 1st item found in subquery but if i replace

```
WHERE cid IN (n.category)
```

with

```
WHERE cid IN (19,18,3)
```

it's work well but as u can see that isn't dynamic
do u know why  n.category limit to just one item?

idk if u need that but a sintetic strucure of tables is

```
ods_news                          ods_category
id      | category                cid     | short
1       | 1                       1       | AA
2       | 3                       2       | BB
3       | 4,5                     3       | CC
4       | 1,2,4                   4       | DD
5       | 6                       5       | EE
6       | 2,1,6                   6       | FF
```

that is the results i have and what i want

```
results i get                     result i want
category | catstring              category | catstring
1        | AA                     1        | AA    
3        | CC                     3        | CC
4,5      | DD                     4,5      | DD,EE
1,2,4    | AA                     1,2,4    | AA,BB,DD
6        | FF                     6        | FF
2,1,6    | BB                     2,1,6    | BB,AA,FF
```

Comment: It sounds like it would make more sense for categories for news items to be a separate table for a many-to-many approach, rather than stored as a comma-separated string. It's going to be harder to work with it in its current form. Using `IN` won't work the way you want when category is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created your test data and replaced the IN() with another function. It gives exactly the results you want:

```
SELECT category, REPLACE((
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `short` SEPARATOR ', ' )
  FROM `ods_category` 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(cid, REPLACE(n.category, ' ', '')) != 0
  ORDER BY cid
), ' ', '') AS catstring
FROM ods_news AS n
```

Result is:

```
+----------+------------+
| category | catstring  |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | AA         |
| 3        | CC         |
| 4,5      | DD,EE      |
| 1,2,4    | AA,BB,DD   |
| 6        | FF         |
| 2,1,6    | AA,BB,FF   |
+----------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```